# how to display apex job status in vf page

Tags: apex

how we accees apex job status in the vf page by using query logic any suggesttions plz
...thanks

Comment: Hi user25465, what kind of job do you mean ? Questions are often easier to answer when they contain more information and explain us what you have already tried and how you are stuck in progress.

Answer (score 1):

When you execute the batch you get the Apex Job ID. Using that ID you can get the status of the batch. The object ApexAsuncJob hold the status of batch job.

You can query this object as:

```
AsyncApexJob a = [Select Id, Status, ExtendedStatus
        from AsyncApexJob where Id = :apexJobIDVar];
```

Use ActionPoller tag in vf to get status periodically.

Comment: plese give sample programe

Comment: hi Ashwani please Give sample code for that..how i can pass apexJobidvar